# How to annotate boxplots using svyboxplot library in R

Tags: r, statistics, boxplot

I am trying to figure out how to label the boxplots that appear after I use the `svyboxplot` library for R.

I have tried the following:

```
svyboxplot(~ALCANYNO~factor(REGION), design=ihisDesign3, xlab='Region', ylab='Frequency', ylim=c(0,10), colnames=c("Northeast", "Midwest", "South", "West"));
```

[image: Plot created with svyboxplot library in R]
SOLUTION: Add the following to factor:

```
labels = c('Northeast', 'Midwest', 'South', 'West')
```

This changes the example above to the following:

```
svyboxplot(~ALCANYNO~factor(REGION, 
           labels=c('Northeast', 'Midwest', 'South', 'West')),
           design=ihisDesign3, xlab='Region', ylab='Frequency', 
           ylim =c (0, 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Creating a dataset to explain:

```
options(width = 120) 
library (survey) 
library (KernSmooth) 

xd1<- 
"xsmoke age_p psu stratum       wt8 
13601       3    22   2      20  356.5600 
32966       3    38   2      45  434.3562 
63493       1    32   1      87  699.9987 
238175      3    46   1     338  982.8075 
174162      3    40   1     240  273.6313 
220206      3    33   2     308 1477.1688 
118133      3    68   1     159  716.3012 
142859      2    23   1     194 1100.9475 
115253      2    35   2     155  444.3750 
61675       3    31   1      85  769.5963 
189813      3    37   1     263  328.5600 
226274      1    47   2     318  605.8700 
41969       3    71   2      58  597.0150 
167667      3    40   2     230 1030.4637 
225103      3    37   2     316  349.6825 
49894       3    70   2      68  517.7862 
98075       3    46   2     130 1428.7225 
180771      3    50   1     250  652.4188 
137057      3    42   1     186  590.2100 
77705       2    23   1     105 1687.2450 
89106       3    48   1     118  407.6513 
208178      3    50   1     290  556.5000 
100403      3    52   2     133 1481.8200 
221571      1    27   2     310  833.5338 
10823       2    72   1      16 1807.6425 
108431      3    71   2     145  945.6263 
68708       1    46   1      94 1989.3775 
23874       3    23   2      33 1707.8775 
150634      3    19   2     206  761.1500 
231232      3    42   2     326 1487.4113 
184654      2    42   2     255 1715.2375 
215312      3    57   1     300  483.5663 
40713       2    57   2      56 2042.2762 
130309      3    23   1     177  948.5625 
25515       2    55   1      35 2719.7525 
235612      2    83   2     333  603.3537 
13755       2    36   2      20  265.1938 
2441        3    33   1       4 1062.1200 
157327      3    77   1     215 2010.6600 
66502       3    20   2      91 1122.9725 
230778      1    55   2     325 1207.3025 
74805       3    54   1     101 1028.5150 
166556      1    50   1     229 1546.9450 
91914       1    68   1     121  428.5350 
89651       3    59   2     118  143.5437 
149329      3    44   2     204 1064.7725 
212700      2    59   2     295 1050.1163 
454         1    79   1       1  275.5700 
125639      1    27   1     170  785.1037 
55442       3    47   1      76  950.3312 
145132      3    77   1     197 1269.2287 
123069      3    24   1     167  216.1937 
188301      1    55   2     260  426.6313 
852         2    66   2       1 1443.4887 
3582        3    81   1       6  790.8412 
235423      1    44   2     333  659.4238 
42175       2    40   1      59 1089.6762 
57033       3    43   1      78  226.8750 
177273      2    85   1     244  392.7200 
218558      3    40   2     305 1680.2700 
27784       2    45   1      39  280.0550 
81823       3    43   1     110  965.0438 
76344       3    26   1     103 1095.6012 
114916      3    56   2     154  436.8838 
35563       3    78   1      49  333.2875 
192279      3    30   2     267  722.0312 
61315       1    48   2      84 1426.5725 
219903      3    43   1     308  791.5738 
42612       3    25   1      60  658.1387 
178488      3    33   2     246  675.1912 
9031        1    27   2      14  989.4863 
145092      2    64   1     197  960.1912 
71885       3    53   2      97  595.4050 
38137       2    75   1      53 1004.0912 
140149      1    21   1     190 1870.9350 
162052      3    25   1     223  892.7775 
89527       2    39   2     118  518.1050 
59650       3    26   2      82  432.7837 
24709       2    84   1      34  453.9013 
18933       3    85   1      27  582.3288 
24904       3    35   2      34 1027.5287 
213668      3    39   1     298 3174.1925 
110509      3    30   1     149  469.8188 
72462       3    63   1      98  386.2163 
152596      3    19   1     209 1328.2188 
17014       4    62   1      24  294.9250 
33467       2    50   1      46 1601.4575 
5241        3    33   1       9 1651.0988 
215094      3    23   1     300  427.6313 
88885       1    21   1     118 1092.2613 
204868      2    60   2     285  781.2325 
157415      2    31   2     215 1323.5750 
71081       2    44   2      96 1059.2088 
25420       3    38   1      35  530.7413 
144226      1    27   1     196 1126.3112 
47888       3    46   2      66  965.4050 
216179      3    29   2     301 1237.6463 
29172       3    68   1      41 1025.9738 
168786      1    47   1     232  680.6213 
94035       2    23   2     124  330.4563 
170542      1    25   2     234  757.2287 
160331      2    33   2     220  636.3900 
124163      3    80   2     167  287.6988 
71442       2    37   1      97  442.2300 
80191       2    74   2     107  871.0338 
199309      3    29   2     277  485.2337 
91293       3    35   2     120  138.3187 
219524      2    68   1     307  609.5862 
119336      3    85   2     160  149.7612 
31814       3    68   1      44  396.6913 
54920       1    28   2      75  532.7175 
161034      3    29   2     221  791.0100 
177037      1    50   1     244  626.2400 
119963      1    54   1     162  374.1062 
107972      2    58   1     145  944.8863 
22932       3    60   1      32  310.6413 
54197       3    23   2      74  931.2737 
209598      3    23   1     292 1078.2950 
213604      1    74   2     297  588.5000 
146480      3    27   1     200  212.0588 
162463      3    55   2     223 1202.0925 
215534      3    33   2     300  430.3938 
100703      1    53   1     134  463.6200 
162588      3    27   1     224  612.0250 
222676      1    35   1     312  292.7000 
220052      3    84   1     308 1301.4738 
131382      3    36   1     178  825.9512 
102117      3    28   1     137  451.4075 
70362       3    52   2      95  185.2562 
188757      3    22   2     261  704.3913 
215878      2    37   1     301  789.9837 
45820       3    18   2      64 2019.4137 
84860       3    47   1     113  149.0200 
110581      3    37   1     149  526.0775 
207650      3    51   2     289  688.0538 
40723       3    59   2      56  497.6050 
169663      3    19   2     233  845.0362 
191955      1    36   1     267  735.7350 
213816      3    18   2     298 2275.3513 
120967      3    48   2     163 1055.3238 
209430      2    42   2     291 1771.0225 
21235       3    21   1      30 1204.5663 
131326      3    29   1     178  331.9588 
19667       1    57   1      28  638.9138 
74743       2    48   1     101 1208.8763 
178672      3    66   2     246  338.2013 
100174      3    24   2     133 1733.6275 
69046       3    24   2      94  542.4863 
79960       1    41   2     107  567.6363 
108591      2    42   1     146  978.3775 
235635      3    24   1     334 1382.9437 
187426      2    54   2     259  478.2362 
28728       3    39   2      40 1165.6175 
205348      3    32   2     286 1082.9913 
218812      3    30   1     306  308.1037 
168389      3    48   2     231  593.2475 
145479      1    21   1     198  864.2663 
105170      2    40   1     141 1016.7862 
155753      2    78   2     212 1109.0025 
169399      3    28   1     233 1467.1363 
55664       1    63   1      76  904.3763 
74024       2    51   1     100  547.5538 
85558       1    25   1     114  893.8825 
142684      3    54   2     193 1203.3212 
198792      1    22   1     277 1800.3325 
82603       3    70   2     110  827.3763 
171036      2    50   2     235 2003.9725 
1616        1    42   2       2  590.5662 
57042       3    45   1      78 1021.7287 
45100       2    38   2      63 1807.9288 
134828      2    28   1     183  715.1187 
91167       3    26   2     120  480.1950 
170605      3    40   2     234  507.2763 
175869      3    77   1     242  386.2987 
81594       2    82   2     109  580.0838 
37426       1    20   2      52 1159.1613 
113799      3    85   1     153  459.5450 
24721       3    18   2      34 2912.7575 
26297       3    45   2      36 1304.4925 
57074       1    51   1      78  602.2112 
185000      3    34   1     256  583.5738 
94196       3    44   2     124 2344.1087 
80656       3    45   2     108 1340.9713 
14849       1    46   1      22  967.2525 
145730      2    73   1     198  418.8037 
56633       3    34   2      77 1011.5488 
273         2    54   1       1  786.2138 
60567       1    40   2      83  315.2925 
47788       1    38   2      66 1105.9188 
76943       2    53   2     103  537.7062 
165014      3    34   1     227  824.3125 
188444      3    22   1     261  623.2225 
29043       1    35   1      41  724.9025 
165578      3    25   1     228  596.0275 
50702       3    43   2      69  985.9662 
197621      3    39   2     275 1310.1163 
26267       3    41   2      36 1030.3900 
29565       1    60   2      41  920.8550 
20060       3    36   2      28  157.2188 
119780      2    20   1     162  863.8100" 
tor <- read.table(textConnection(xd1), header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE) 

# Grouping variable "xsmoke"  must be a factor 

tor$xsmoke <- factor(tor$xsmoke,levels=c (1,2,3), 
                labels=c('Current SMK','Former SMK', 'Never Smk'), ordered=TRUE) 

is.factor(tor$xsmoke)     


# object with survey design variables and data 
nhis <- svydesign (id=~psu,strat=~stratum, weights=~wt8, data=tor, nest=TRUE) 

MyBreaks <- c(18, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85) 



svyboxplot (age_p~xsmoke, 
            subset (nhis, age_p>=0), 
            col=c("red", "yellow", "green"), medcol="blue", 
            varwidth=TRUE, all.outliers=TRUE, 
            ylab="Age at Interview", 
            xlab=" " 
            )
```

The Factor variable `xsmoke` is coded as `tor$xsmoke <- factor(tor$xsmoke,levels=c (1,2,3), 
                    labels=c('Current SMK','Former SMK', 'Never Smk'), ordered=TRUE)`  which should be useful

[image]

__________________________________________`enter code here`

Comment: Would you mind accepting this as answer - if it solves your purpose